# transfer file from remote unix server to your windows system

Tags: unix

hi can anyone please tell how to transfer a file on ubuntu to my local windows 10 machine.......

Comment: Use `FTP` but be careful: in case your file is a special UNIX file (like a symlink), strange things might happen.

Comment: FTP.. SFTP. FTPS. HTTPS. Shared drive. `rcp`. `scp`. ...

Answer (score 3):

You can download winscp and congfigure the username and password.And then connect to your unix box you would able to see file system